# How can I manage iCloud Backup?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, backup

My iPhone as well as mini iPad give me the statement "this has not been backed up for so many weeks as there isn't enough room in icloud. I am not as savy as I wish. I plug them into my computer and today the iPad only copied over my photos. I then deleted thinking that would free up space. What am I doing that is causing them to not have enough space? I don't watch videos or movies. Anyone I ask if it comes up on their phones or pads says it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use icloud for contacts, not photos. Photos take up a lot of room on icloud. Do you have itunes? Assuming so - create a backup on your PC-- you will be given an option upon plug in to backup "now" ? If you aren't you can go into your settings and do a complete backup now - make sure you have ticks next to each item you want backed up. i.e. photos, apps etc.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage

That will show you what is taking up the space and will give you the option to delete an app's data.

Tapping on one of your devices at the top of the list will give you a place to turn off an app's ability to back things up on iCloud if it seems to always be using too much room.